# Testing a Builder Pattern

Tags: java, testing, mocking, builder

I'm trying to unit test a builder style pattern which looks like this (mockedObject is injected into the function so I can mock it):

```
Thing thing = 
    mockedObject.createThing()
     .addParam1()
     .addParam2(mockedObject.createParam2()
                   .someData()
                   .build())
    .build();

mockedObject.use(thing);
```

I'm trying to work out how to test this (using JUnit and Easymock) without have to mock out the entire builder object. All I need to test on the resultant object is that `param1` and `param2` were set with specific values.

Mocking out the entire builder pattern would make the test extremely brittle and its not what I should be testing to begin with.

Is there a (better) way to test this?

Answer (score 0):

via Mokito and JUnit5 you can use RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS for your mock. for example here is an example:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
class TargetClassTest {
 private static final long SUBJECT_ID;


 @Mock 
 private AuthService authService;

 @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)  // deeply stubbed
 private Logger logger;

 @InjectMocks
 private TargetClass service;


 @Test
 void test_whenSomething_thenResult() {
    service.command(SUBJECT_ID);

    verify(logger,times(1)).builder(eq(SUBJECT_ID));
    verify(loggerbuilder(eq(SUBJECT_ID)),times(1)).thirdPartyLog(eq(DATA_DOG));
    verify(loggerbuilder(eq(SUBJECT_ID)).thirdPartyLog(DATA_DOG),times(1)).send();

 }


}
```

as you can see above, I created a deeply stubbed mock for the builder then I could assure that it called properly with proper parameters.